# Date aggregation on Presto

Tags: sql, date, presto

I have a table that has the list of products sold each day and would like to know what date is when we had the 95th percentile of sale (for a given product). I am not looking at averages as there are days when the sales are high (and can skew the numbers)

Here is the query am trying to run on presto

```
select approx_percentile(count(date), .95) 
from logs 
where vendor='abc' 
  and product='biscuit' 
  and date >= date_parse(date_format(now() - interval '30' day, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

But presto does not seem to like it and throws the below error message

> Query  failed: Unexpected parameters (date, double) for function approx_percentile. Expected: approx_percentile(bigint, double) , approx_percentile(bigint, bigint, double) , approx_percentile(double, double) , approx_percentile(double, bigint, double)

PS : date is of the Type 'date'

Comment: Every sale has a timestamp that includes the Date and so this is my best option to get the stats.

Comment: Can you provide your column name so that will provide you a query

Comment: Hi @JimMacaulay, every sale will have the date, vendor, item and price. So date is what is common to every transaction.

Comment: I think you need to separate counting dates in a nested query then use it in `approx_percentile(cnt, .95)` ;).

Answer (score 0):

`select product,date,count(sale)
  from logs 
   where vendor='abc' and product = 'biscuit'
   group by product,date order by count(sale) desc;`

This query will give you all the details with maximum sale at the top.